# Fetching Chef recipe name inside chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I have couple of library functions which are common across all recipes in given cookbook. So if I provide name of recipe those library functions can do expected behavior change for particular recipe.

Similar case with template locations, recipe specific templates are stored under directory named after recipe.

Now inside chef recipe during runtime , how to determine name of running recipe which can allow me to leverage above template directory structure and library functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `recipe_name` method

```
Chef::Log.info("I am a message from the #{recipe_name} recipe in the #{cookbook_name} cookbook.")
```

Source: https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#recipe-name